# Create Combinations of XML data sets

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a complicated problem where the following table defines possible values for each parameter (delimited by `;`):

```
paramname   paramvalues
=====================================
p1          10;20;30;40;50;60;70;80;90;100;150;200
p2          yes;no
p3          apple;orange
p4          0.001;0.002;0.003;0.05;0.08;0.09;0.1;0.2
p5          1000;2000;5000;10000;20000
p6          10;20;50;100
```

So for the above, I want to create a record for every single combination of parameter values.  Each record will specify the parameter combination as XML, e.g.:

```
<data>
    <p1>12</p1>
    <p2>yes</p2>
    <p3>apple</p3>
    <p4>0.001</p4>
    <p5>1000</p5>
    <p6>50</p6>
</data>
```

So the above shows just one record out of a possible 7680 records (being 12x2x2x8x5x4 which is the total possible combinations of the above)

I would like a script that can create these records in a table var e.g.:

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE(combo xml)
```

Please note paramname is dynamic, so cannot hard code `<p1>, <p2>`, etc in code.  I have been able to do this manually by creating 6 temporary tables, loading the parameters as records and doing a series of LEFT JOINS. But of course this wont work here.

Comment: Quite easy with Postgres: http://rextester.com/UTNW62905

Comment: True, it's SQL server... I did figure it out, was a bit tricky I need to clean up my code will post solution soon...